# PHP IDE for Ubuntu Netbook Remix 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, php, eclipse, ubuntu-netbook-remix

I've installed Ubuntu Netbook Remix on my netbook and I'm wondering what would be a good IDE to use for *mainly* PHP development. I've used Komodo Edit in past Linux distributions but it doesn't seem to play well with Ubuntu Network Remix (it doesn't shows up in the remix "desktop", and I don't feel like opening the terminal and typing `komodo` every time I need to code).

I'm considering [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with a PHP plugin, but I've two big problems with Eclipse:

1. I don't like the way it forces me to create a new project when I just want to edit a file.
2. I'm not sure which PHP plugin I should install: [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/), [PHP Eclipse](http://www.phpeclipse.com/) or [Aptana](http://www.aptana.org/studio/plugin) - I don't really understand the differences between Eclipse PDT and PHP Eclipse.

Which IDE would you recommend (doesn't need to be Eclipse)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went with [Geany](http://www.geany.org/): installs out of the box, integrates well with UNR, it's lightweight and supports PHP syntax among many more other languages.

> Some basic features of Geany:
>
> - Syntax highlighting
> - Code folding
> - Symbol name auto-completion
> - Construct completion/snippets
> - Auto-closing of XML and HTML tags
> - Call tips
> - Many supported filetypes including C, Java, PHP, HTML, Python, Perl,
>     Pascal (full list)
> - Symbol lists
> - Code navigation
> - Build system to compile and execute your code
> - Simple project management
> - Plugin interface (see Plugins)

[image: Geany]

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org). Open source, and works well for PHP, JavaScript and Ajax, Ruby and Ruby on Rails, Groovy and Grails, and C/C++.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm installing it and I'll try it out.

Comment: Okay, I've tried it and it seems a lot nicer than Eclipse, however I've the same problem (I've to create a project every time I need to create a new file). I'll probably use this in lack of a better alternative, though.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use and recommend VIM....it's powerful, light and totally customizable. You can find scripts and plugins to get it to do anything you want.